# Question on Inequalities involving random variables

Tags: random-variable, probability-inequalities

If $N(k)$ be the number of $X_i$'s such that $|X_i - \bar{X}| \geq k.s$ for some $k > 0$, how can we show that $$\frac{N(k)}{n} \leq \frac{1}{k^2} \;\;\;\;?$$

Here, $\bar{X}$ and $s$ are the mean and s.d. of the data set $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$.

Additional query : What will be the significance of the result if $k = 3$ ?

Comment: (1) You must be missing a factor of $s$ somewhere in the inequality. (2) Apply Chebyshev's Inequality to the empirical distribution function of the $X_i$. (3) When you do, which way does the inequality go?

Comment: Yes, Chebyshev's inequality solves it. Just solved it myself. 

My additional query is - What will be the significance of the result if $k = 3$ ?

Comment: Since this is not a formal test, you cannot mean "significance" in the usual statistical sense--but what do you mean by that?  Do you mean of what use would such an inequality be in practice?